# Create slowly internet simulation on local server

Tags: networking, latency

I want test some, while my site is loading.
Currently i dont have real server and I test my site on local server and my local site is loaded very fast of course,  I want create artificially slowly internet simulation on local server, please tell, this possibly? if yes, how make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [YSlow](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=yslow&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=586a8f8a87a950e2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1680&bih=935) plugin to simulate it in your browser

Answer (score 0):

Traffic control program can simulate this.

e.g.:

```
tc qdisc replace dev lo root handle 1:0 netem delay 500msec
```

For 0.5s delay for each packet.